# IOS StoryBoard multiple Segue's from a TableCell

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

Hi I have a storyboard and am able to show a detail view when clicking on a table cell. I want to add extra functionality so that depending on what cell I click I show a different view controller. I tried dragging two segues from the same cell but it doesn't allow it.

My thinking was that I would have two segue's from the cell each pointing to a different view and then invoke the desired segue:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"Selected Item :-) %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myData objectAtIndex:row]]);
    if(row %2 ==0){
        NSLog(@"Even");        
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSecondIndex" sender:self];
    }else{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSelectedMovie" sender:self];
        NSLog(@"Odd");

    }

}
```

I would then handle the segue in prepareForSegue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@"Prepare For Segue ID:%@",[segue identifier]);

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSelectedMovie"]){
        Tab2_ItemViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
        NSLog(@"Selected Index: %d",selectedIndex);
        [vc setSelectedItem: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myData objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]]];
        NSLog(@"String Value: %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myData objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]]);
        [vc setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex];


    }else if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSecondIndex"]){

        NSLog(@"Viewing Second Index");
    }

}
```

However it never shows the second view. Is this because its not possible to have two segues from a single table cell. I also tried dragging both segue's from the controller to each destination rather than one from the cell and one from the controller but sill no luck???

Comment: @casperOne - Why did you close this? If you don't understand the question, ignore it. This is a VERY common question with people trying to use Storyboards. Please un-close.

Comment: Agreed totally. Surely this was closed by accident? Please unclose.

Comment: Ditto. This was probably closed by mistake.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Don't try to hook up the Segues to a tableviewcell in this case.  Hook them up to the View Controller itself.

Comment: I tried this but still no luck, only one of the views was called

Comment: This has to work.  I do this all the time.  Delete the Segues you have to that VC now and add them back making sure to connect each segue to the VC itself.  Then you can call [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueID" sender:nil]; on the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Sweet! I didn't know you could have segue's from the view controller, I thought they could only go from like a button or similar. :) I'm liking segues a bit more now.

Comment: @ElJay Great answer, though you probably meant to say View Controller, not just View. (You say as much in your comment, but the abbreviation VC might not be clear to all.)

Comment: Could you flesh this answer out a bit?  It's little more than a comment.

Comment: How do you mean?  I don't think there is any other way to explain it other than how I did.

Comment: @LJWilson : I  want to set couple of variable in the destinationController before performing the segue using **self.performSegueWithIdentifier** in swift. If it was prepareForSegue i can easily use the segue variable from function and create a controller based on the destination controller as **let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! PDFDocumentViewController** and but how to do this while using **self.perforSegue** inside **didSelectRowAtIndex**??

Comment: You would set any properties in the destinationController inside the prepareForSegue method.

Answer (score 47):

Don't try to create multiple segues from a TableCell to other view controllers, you want to ctrl+drag from the view controller icon below the view controller in the storyboard interface to the viewcontrollers you want to segue to. Then it will allow you to set up multiple segues.

[image: screenshot showing multiple segues]

and then to actually make the segues work, you need to add identifiers to the segues themselves, which you can do by clicking on them and then giving it a name in the property inspector:

[image: giving segue an identifier]

then, for the example of TableCells, in your UITableViewDelegate, in

```
-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

you can use

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

to manually start a segue depending on your own logic of what segue should be chosen.

Comment: This is the superior answer as Interface Builder with Storyboards is not super intuitive. Knowing where you control click *from* is the key :)

Comment: Thank you for describing exactly how to do this in IB!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sample code from my demo project:

```
-         (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *segueName = nil;

    if (type == kCore) {
        segueName = @"segue1";
    } else if (type == kStdlib) {
        segueName = @"segue2";
    }

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: segueName sender: self];
}
```

`type` is a property of view controller, which determines which segue should be performed.

As the above answer said, the key is to create segue by linking two view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3.1, with a segment control of two states

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
var segue: String!
if selectedSegment == 0 {
    segue = "segue1"
} else  {
    segue = "segue2"
}
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segue, sender: self)
```

}