# Nested push animation, but there's no push?

Tags: uitableview, ios6, xcode4.5, uistoryboardsegue

I am getting this error when I try to preform a segue...

```
2012-11-14 20:24:54.133 MyApp[26266:c07] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2012-11-14 20:24:54.486 MyApp[26266:c07] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2012-11-14 20:24:54.487 MyApp[26266:c07] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <SheetDrillDownViewController: 0xa1bb980>.
```

Here is my setup: Initial view --> next view (UITableView) --> last view (UITable)

Each cell pushes to another view until the last view.  I do not have a modal segue, i have a push segue... I have the push segues linked from the cell to the next view, each with different names...  I have a perform segue line in my selectedRowAtIndex method.  I have tried removing that method, with people saying I am double calling the segue, but then the cell when clicked turns blue, and doesn't push to anywhere...  How can I fix this error? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"subjectDrillDown" sender:nil];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Attempting to identify segue...");
    // Make sure we're referring to the correct segue
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"subjectDrillDown"]) {

        NSLog(@"Segue has been identified...");
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        SubjectDrillDownViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]; 
        NSMutableDictionary *object = [tableDataSource objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
        NSString *key = [object valueForKey:@"key"];
        [vc setSelectedItem:key];

        NSLog(@"Switching to %@ detail view...",key);
        NSLog(@"Passing dictionary to %@ view... (Source below)\n\n %@",key,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tableDataSource objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]]);
        [vc setDetailDataSourceDict:[tableDataSource objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"ERROR, DOUBLE CHECK SEGUE'S NAME!");
    }
}
```

---

I have seen all of the other Stack Overflow questions, but most of the correct answers don't work for me...

---

### EDIT:

The next view is able to load, but when I click the back button, there are suddenly two more views...

---

### UPDATE:

[image]

I will try to post the number of times Attempting to identify segue... NSLogs, but my compiler suddenly won't run :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You surely don't need to perform segue in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, if you have already configured it like cell -> next view.

But, removing the call from there doesn't work for you then you can try the segue from view controller (ctrl+drag from view area) to next view and keep the segue call in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

---

I always use one of the following methods

**Method 1:**

Segue from `UITableViewCell` to `Next View Controller`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Nothing
}
```

**Method 2:**

Segue from `Main View Controller` to `Next View Controller`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"subjectDrillDown" sender:nil];
}
```

The error you are getting is because you have segue and you perform the segue manually when selected - hence, it is resulting in **nested push animation**

Make sure the name of the segue is correct and you are using ONLY one of the above methods

Comment: I tried that, but xcode won't let me drag into the next view from the previous view.  It only allows from the cell to the next view...

Comment: Delete current segue and try again - refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837944/ios-storyboard-multiple-segues-from-a-tablecell

Comment: Please post screenshot of your storyboard. How many times `Attempting to identify segue...` gets printed?

Comment: Does the segue works when you click on cell in `Subject drill down` to open `Sheet drill down`?

Comment: Also, post your output by keeping segue configured from cell to view and removing everything from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19564/discussion-between-user1789040-and-user427969)