# iOS - navigation from one screen to multiple screens

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have 4 ViewControllers (let's say A, B, C and D). A contains an UITableView and this allows user to navigate from A to B, A to C, A to D. How can I connect my Table cell to all these 3 (B, C, D) view controllers using segue? or any other possible work around?
I am using Xcode 5 and storyboards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control-drag from the cell in the table view to the view controller you want to link to allow the user to navigate to that screen when that cell it tapped.

Here is how to do it:
[image: Tutorial]

This is the result (I added some elements to make it clearer):
[image: Result]

Learn more about storyboards [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: no. it doesn't work. When I control-drag second time, first segue disappears.

Comment: @ChaturaM are you sure that you're dragging from a different cell than the first? You might also be dragging from the actual storyboard, not the cell. Try going into the sidebar and dragging from the cell element there, instead of from the canvas.

Comment: I found the answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837944/ios-storyboard-multiple-segues-from-a-tablecell

Comment: That works, but you're using a storyboard, so you should create the segue visually.

Comment: @ChaturaM I added a GIF to help you out.