# How to access segue in 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, segue

I know how to pass data using segues from **prepareForSegue** function, but the thing i have a TableViewCell from which there are two possible segues to two different ViewControllers (let's just say A, B as of now).

It was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837944/ios-storyboard-multiple-segues-from-a-tablecell) that it is best to connect the segues to View controller rather than the tableCell itself, which infact worked perfectly. But i want to pass information to the second View controller when the cell is clicked, So how to access **segue** that i connected to the Source ViewController.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if segue.identifier == "showQuestionnaire"{
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
      let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! QuestionnaireController
      let patientQuestionnaire = patientQuestionnaires[indexPath.row] as! PatientQuestionnaire
      controller.selectedQuestionnaire = patientQuestionnaire
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showQuestionnaire", sender: self)
    }
  }
}
```

Again: This question is not regarding passing information through **prepareForSegue**

Comment: I do not get the question, but if the question is how to send data to the prepareForSegue, use the sender field of the performSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[A_VC class]]) {...} else {...}

Comment: Passing the information in `prepareForSegue` is the correct way to do it.  You definitely should not be calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` inside `prepareForSegue` though.

Comment: It looks like you are already passing information to the next view controller with the `let controller = segue.destination as...` line. What specifically are you trying to do that isn't being done in that function? And as mentioned elsewhere, do not call `performSegueWithIdentifier` inside `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Guys, i'm trying to set the **controller. selectedQuestionnaire** while performing the segue from didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but at the end, it performs the segue to my destination controller but it is not setting the  **selectedQuestionnaire** value inside of it, i think that is because i cannot access the segue that is connected to the source view controller to create a DestinationViewController **JUST LIKE** in prepareforSegue function. I hope i'm clear this time.

Comment: Your problem is not from the inability to access the segue, because prepareForSegue is the way to go if you want to set something (but something is obviously awry when you're setting that variable, but its not at the fault of `prepareForSegue`) **When you say that selectedQuestionnaire is not being set, is it nil?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should be using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to determine whether or not a cell was selected, and send the `indexPath` as the sender of the segue:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showQuestionnaire", sender: indexPath);
}
```

Then in your `prepareForSegue` method, get the `indexPath` from the `sender` parameter and use that to pass the correct row/data:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showQuestionnaire") {
        let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! QuestionnaireController
        let row = (sender as! NSIndexPath).row; //we know that sender is an NSIndexPath here.
        let patientQuestionnaire = patientQuestionnaires[row] as! PatientQuestionnaire 
        controller.selectedQuestionnaire = patientQuestionnaire
    }
}
```

To explain...

1. I used the index path as the sender so I can easily pass the index path. You could also check for the currently selected cell using other UITableView methods, but I've always done it this way with success
2. You can't put `performSegueWithIdentifier` within the prepare for segue method, because `performSegueWithIdentifier` leads to `prepareForSegue`; You are just looping around and around with no aim. (When you want to perform a segue, prepareForSegue is always executed)
3. `prepareForSegue` doesn't run by itself when a row is selected. This is where you need `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. You need a `performSegueWithIdentifier` outside of the method as described previously, which should be in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I tried your solution, but it gives this error on line `let controller = (segue.destinationVIewController....` . **Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x105866418) to 'CarePortal.QuestionnaireController' (0x1034f1850).**

Comment: You're probably setting the wrong object type to the cast, could you check and make sure that everything you've casted is what you've described?

Comment: Changing **as!** to **as?** did the trick. Thanks @Nate. Swift is really getting strict about optional values :@

Comment: Yup, just keep in mind in the future, **the device must know you want to perform a segue so that it knows prepare for it** :)

Comment: I got a question about this solution. If the user is double tapping the cell (accidentally), then performSegue will be triggered twice. How do I make sure it only triggers once?