# passing data from plist to DetailView

Tags: swift, dictionary, annotations, plist

I am moving from Objective C to Swift and rewriting my Apps. Having a problem with a basic issue at the moment so would appreciate any help.

I have set up a map with annotations taken from plist data which works fine. I can also pass the title and subtitle to a second view controller - no problem.

However, I want to pass all the other fields of the data of the selected item as well and this is what I am having a problem with.

Did it fine before but cannot find any indication of how to do it in Swift despite a lot of searching. An example would be perfect :-)

```
import MapKit

class Museums: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var state: String?
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude:Double
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }

    init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }
}






class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var infoToPass: String?

    //View did load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       mapView.delegate = self

        zoomToRegion()

        let annotations = getMapAnnotations()

        // Add mappoints to Map
        mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)

        mapView.delegate = self

        }



    //Zoom to region

    func zoomToRegion() {

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 39.8, longitude: -98.6)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 3150000.0, 3150000.0)

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    // Annotations

    func getMapAnnotations() -> [Museums] {
        var annotations:Array = [Museums]()

        //load plist file           
        var myMuseums: NSArray?
        if let path =    NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyAnnotationsUSA", ofType: "plist") {
            myMuseums = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
        }
        if let items = myMuseums {
            for item in items {
                let lat = item.valueForKey("latitude") as! Double
                let long = item.valueForKey("longitude")as! Double
                let annotation = Museums(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
                annotation.title = item.valueForKey("title") as? String
                annotation.state = item.valueForKey("state") as? String
                annotations.append(annotation)
            }
        }

        return annotations
    }


    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotations: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let reuseIdentifier = "pin"
        var pin = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if pin == nil {
            pin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotations, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            //             pin!.pinColor = .Red
            pin!.canShowCallout = true
            pin!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
        } else
        {
            pin!.annotation = annotations
        }
        return pin
}



func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
    }
}


//prepare for segue

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if self.mapView.selectedAnnotations.count == 0 {
            //no annotation selected
            return;
        }


        let  titleToPass = self.mapView.selectedAnnotations[0] //as? MKAnnotation

        print("\(infoToPass.title!)")

        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

        //This works
        destination.myLabelText = infoToPass.title!
        // This does not
        destination.myStateText = infoToPass.state

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a stylistic comment about your sample code: the excessive whitespace and inconsistent indentation hurts my brain a bit :-)

Comment: Jere. Oops. Sorry. Hope your brain has recovered :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your `DetailViewController`, you should declare the properties that hold the additional data. Then, set those properties in your `prepareForSegue`method, just like you set the `myLabelText`. This should really be no different than in Objective-C, apart from the obvious differences between the two languages.

Or, if there is something more to this than what seems obvious, please add some more information to your question.

**UPDATE**: After reviewing your comments and recreating your sample in Xcode, it seems that since you're getting the selected annotation back as `MKAnnotation` from the map view, it will obviously not have the `state` member. Try casting it to `Museums`, like so:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if self.mapView.selectedAnnotations.count == 0 {
        //no annotation selected
        return
    }

    let infoToPass = self.mapView.selectedAnnotations[0] as! Museums  // <-- NOTE
    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
    destination.myLabelText = infoToPass.title!
    destination.myStateText = infoToPass.state
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I was unable to get it to work. I set up one of the fields to pass on its content  to the DetailViewController in exactly the same way as I did the Title (a field called state in the plist). However, I get the error message 'value of the MKAnnotation has no member 'state'. There is no problem doing this with subTitle or Lat/Long but it's the other fields in the plist which I am having a problem with. As always, help/advice much appreciated

Comment: Thinking it through, I have defined a class for NSObject, MKAnnotation and I know that class has properties for  title, subtitle, latitude, longitude and coordinate. So that is working for me in terms of passing title etc. But my problem is accessing the parts of in a plist which are MKAnnotation properties. Doing exactly the same thing for a field such as one I have called 'state' gives an error of 'Value of type MKAnnotation has no member 'state'"

Comment: errata: that should have been "..assessing the parts in a plist which are NOT MKAnnotation properties.

Comment: Hmm, are you passing the MKAnnotation instance and the state separately? The error message you're getting makes me think that you're trying to retrieve the state from the MKAnnotation instance. You would need two member variables in your detail view controller (or more than two if you have several items related to the MKAnnotation but not its members).

Comment: Hi Jere. I have updated my code snippet and added the Class where the MKAnnotation info is set up. I have no problem passing Title, Subtitle, lat and long which are MKAnnotation properties. What I am trying to figure out is how one adds/extracts other info from the selected annotation. I get the error of "value of type MKAnnotation has no member 'state". Put simply my questions is, how does one access the other information?

Comment: OK, I didn't realize that you were implementing the MKAnnotation protocol. If you're declaring the data as MKAnnotation in DetailViewController, that would explain why the 'state' member is not available. In that case you should declare it as Museums instead.

Comment: But I'm not declaring the data in the DetailViewController. MKAnnotation is declared in the Class Museums. That is then used in the ViewController.Swift which puts the plist data into an array, which in turn populates the pin annotations. As I said, I can forward the Title etc to DetailViewController but do not know how to make the other data from the selected record available

Comment: See the update to my answer - does it help? You have to declare *something* in DetailViewController, to hold the additional data. However, your problem seems to be in getting the additional data out of the Museums instance. But you should be able to do that by casting the selected annotation to Museums. If you don't do that, the title field works fine, because it is declared by MKAnnotation. But the state field doesn't, since it is declared by the Museums type, not by MKAnnotation.

Comment: Jere, thank you so much. It now does what it is supposed to do. Seems so obvious now you have pointed it out but I have been tearing my hair out (or would be if I had any)!

So thank you again for taking the time and effort to share. I know this questions comes up again and again so I will, in turn, pass on the info :-)

Now, on to the next problem which is bound to arise :-)

Comment: Jere, can I ask you a supplementary question. What is the syntax for doing the same thing, passing the selected plist record, but from a TableView to a DetailView. I guess I am asking what is the equivalent of the line of code:  
let  titleToPass = self.mapView.selectedAnnotations[0] as? Museums

Comment: From your table view data source, get the item corresponding to the selected/desired table view cell. If you're overriding `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you'll get an `NSIndexPath` instance that helps you determine the item in your model. But you'll find many questions and answers about this on SO, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974864/how-to-access-segue-in-didselectrowatindexpath-swift-ios